# Is there a Python function to +1 to a value in a column if it is the same as previous row to keep the sequence increasing?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have some time-series data that I would like to alter if there are values that are the same.

...

```
df = [{'period':'1', 'period_secs':1},
{'period':'1', 'period_secs':2},
{'period':'1', 'period_secs':3}
{'period':'1', 'period_secs':3},
{'period':'1', 'period_secs':3},
{'period':'1', 'period_secs':4}]
```

...

gives me:

```
|period   |period_secs|
|    1    |     2     |
|    1    |     3     |
|    1    |     3     |
|    1    |     3     |
|    1    |     4     |
|    1    |     8     |
```

I would like to either add a new column that will continue the sequence so no number is duplicated and always increasing.
Which would give me

```
|period   |period_secs|period_secs_new|
|    1    |     2     |       2       |
|    1    |     3     |       3       |
|    1    |     3     |       4       |
|    1    |     3     |       5       |
|    1    |     4     |       6       |
|    1    |     8     |       8       |
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Because it's time series data. I can't have a time occurring more than once as I have to merge it with another df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution with accumulate:

```py
    from itertools import accumulate

    def index_count(sum_, new_val):
        return new_val if new_val > sum_ else sum_ + 1

    df['period_secs_new'] = list(accumulate(df['period_secs'], func=index_count))
```

Output:

```
  period  period_secs  period_secs_new
0      1            1                1
1      1            2                2
2      1            3                3
3      1            3                4
4      1            3                5
5      1            6                6
6      1            8                8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) while using the new (in 3.8) [Walrus-operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'period':'1', 'period_secs':2},
{'period':'1', 'period_secs':3},
{'period':'1', 'period_secs':3},
{'period':'1', 'period_secs':3},
{'period':'1', 'period_secs':4},
{'period':'1', 'period_secs':8}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Creating the new column to loop over
df["period_secs_new"] = df["period_secs"]

# A while-loop that is True while there are still
# consecutive values that are the same
while any(d:= df.period_secs_new.eq(df.period_secs_new.shift())):
    df.loc[d, ("period_secs_new",)] = df.loc[d, ("period_secs_new",)].apply(lambda x: x+1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  period  period_secs  period_secs_new
0      1            2                2
1      1            3                3
2      1            3                4
3      1            3                5
4      1            4                6
5      1            8                8
```